# Map secondary domain to other's virtual subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm working on a Wordpress site and there's a request to map:

```
http://otherdomain.com
```

to:

```
http://maindomain.com/virtualsubfolder/
```

(the WP site)

This can be easily done, but the URL structure should remain intact i.e.

```
http://otherdomain.com/something/
```

should redirect to:

```
http://maindomain.com/virtualsubfolder/something/
```

but the URL in the client side should remain:

```
http://otherdomain.com/something/
```

I know it's a pretty common problem, but i still couldn't find any viable solution.

I'm open to any ideas using Apache's mod_rewrite or even Nginx.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are they hosted on the same server?

Comment: Yes, and it's even the same Wordpress install. I want to use one domain as usual (so simply pointing to wordpress root) but map the second domain to wordpress-root/something.

Comment: I added an answer that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to set Apache up with a `VirtualHost` for the subdomain and point it to that directory. But I guess if you could do that you would have done it. To make it work off the same `VirtualHost` you can put this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =otherdomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/virtualsubfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ virtualsubfolder/$1
```

Comment: Can't get it working this way, but thanks for the idea.